# Web REPL architecture

Tags: python, web, containers, backend, read-eval-print-loop

I want to make web REPL for my custom interpreter. Let me explane my idea. When user write code in browser and then click "evaluate" button, code goes through linter and validator written in JS (validator and linter will be as separate modules), if OK code sends to server via ajax. Then on server separate environment created for that code evaluation. After evaluation that code, results goes back to broswer. So that thing that I dont know is how and with what tools create that separate environment for client code evaluation. If that is right, my question is: what should I do on server to run client's code safely? separate from main OS I guess. May be docker can help?

Comment: What is your custom program language? Have you specified it (both syntax and semantics)? Is your custom interpreter some free software?

Comment: just simple lisp interpreter

Comment: Lisp or Scheme? What is the URL of the source code? In  what programmig language are you coding your interpreter?

Comment: lisp) I wrote it in python, I am just study and code is bad I think and there is a lot to do. But if you want you can do critics and make comments to help me. https://github.com/egorsmth/lispy

Comment: That github URL should go into the question

Comment: No reason for that, I want to make repl outside of specific interpreter. So infrastructure of web repl will be separate from interpreter. Interpreter will be like module, roughly speaking I can attach any interpreter I want to this web repl.

Comment: Notice how I just improved my answer

Comment: Even added a PS to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use some good HTTP server library like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/). Be sure to understand well [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP).

Even if you have client side validation in JavaScript, don't trust it and repeat the validation on server side. An hostile user could send direct HTTP requests (outside of your AJAX).

Use session and cookies to identify (in  the server) the various client browsers, and keep a separate environment (for your server-side interpreter) for each of them. Implement your re-entrant interpreter with isolation (of sessions and environments) in mind.

Containerization (with docker) is an extra security measure, but design your server side code to be secure (so check everything there) even without that.

If you have not read them already, read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools), [Lisp in Small Pieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces), [Programming language pragmatics](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/), the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/) and this [blog article](https://medium.com/better-programming/object-oriented-programming-the-trillion-dollar-disaster-%EF%B8%8F-92a4b666c7c7), quite related in concepts (but with a *very* different terminology and approach, and indirectly related) to [that one](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/2016/12/bootstrapping-caia-part-i-the-initial-domain/).

> I want to make web REPL for my custom interpreter.

Then you could even take further inspiration from the 1980's [*Mentor* system](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00076535) (and the related, even older, [*Centaur*](ftp://www.inria.fr/pub/rapports/RT-140.ps) one). My [Bismon draft report](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) explains more how and why, but you need to abstract away from its title and skip its first few pages, required by European [H2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framework_Programmes_for_Research_and_Technological_Development#Horizon_2020) bureaucracy. My personal opinion about *Mentor* and *Centaur* is that the ideas described there are more than 25 years ahead of their time, and, given the power of current computers (1000x times better than in 1980s) it is worth resurrecting those old ideas. A probable major cause of the *pragmatical* and *practical* failure of those ideas is, I believe, the lack of computer power in 1980s era workstations.

PS. See also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/393837/40065).

Comment: Thanks, I stopped with lang theory, but still likely to read what you recommend, may get some inspiration :) Also that whole my thing started from SICP.

Comment: In the immortal words of Ron Burgundy, "Well, that escalated quickly." Jokes aside, I would like to print out this answer, and frame it.